# Facebook get number of sent invitations

Tags: facebook

I want save a number of sent invitations in database, this is my code:

> ```
>    $request_ids = explode(",", $_REQUEST['request_ids']); 
>
>       foreach ($request_ids as $id)
>     {             $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO fb_invites (sender_id, recipient_id, created_time) VALUES(".(int)$me['id'].", ".(int)$id.",NOW())";
>       $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
>     }
> ```

```
      }
```

but it does work. Can you say me how can i get a recipient id?

Comment: this:  
$request_ids = explode(",", $_REQUEST['request_ids']); 
does not return recipient id

Comment: I found that now it is Requests 2.0. Can anyone help me how can i get a recipient id?

Answer (score 0):

Please try $_REQUEST["to"] instead of $_REQUEST['request_ids']. I had a similar issue some time before and I tried with $_REQUEST["to"] it works for me. I am not sure if it same now. May be you can give a try.

Comment: Maybe _you_ add something like a _real_ problem description first, instead of just stating “it doesn’t work” all the time!

Comment: My problem is that i can't get a recipient id when I send an invitation, I wrote this several times. I stating that a code which wrote doesn't work, the same code I find on the internet but is out of date. I please somebody who know how currently can get a recipient id for help, all examples which I find are outdated. Sorry for "it doesn't work", but i don't know how I can do this. Sorry also for my english.